# PyroCMS - Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, pyrocms, php-ini

Im receiving an error after testing my PyroCMS module on my hosted test server.

I think it has something to do with the php.ini file and sessions (I have included a subset from the phpinfo output).

The issue appears everytime I start/restart the session.

**The php code where the error appears**

```
if ($this->input->get('session')) {
    session_id($this->input->get('session'));
    session_regenerate_id();
}
```

**error that i get **

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning    

Message: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home2/client555/public_html/addons/staging_twoducks/modules/shop/controllers/checkout.php:1)

Filename: hooks/pick_language.php

Line Number: 30
```

**phpinfo (session settings)**

```
 session
 -----------------
 Session Support                  | enabled
 Registered save handlers         | files user sqlite
 Registered serializer handlers      | php php_binary


 Directive             Local Value  Master Value
 -------------------------------------------------------
 session.auto_start        Off  Off
 session.bug_compat_42         On   On
 session.bug_compat_warn           On   On
 session.cache_expire          180  180
 session.cache_limiter         nocache  nocache
 session.cookie_domain         no value no value
 session.cookie_httponly           Off  Off
 session.cookie_lifetime           0    0
 session.cookie_path           /    /
 session.cookie_secure         Off  Off
 session.entropy_file          no value no value
 session.entropy_length        0    0
 session.gc_divisor                100  100
 session.gc_maxlifetime        1440 1440
 session.gc_probability        1    1
 session.hash_bits_per_character    4   4
 session.hash_function          0   0
 session.name                      PHPSESSID     PHPSESSID
 session.referer_check         no value no value
 session.save_handler          files    files
 session.save_path                 /tmp /tmp
 session.serialize_handler         php  php
 session.use_cookies           On   On
 session.use_only_cookies          On   On
 session.use_trans_sid         0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I just needed to change these two settings in my ini file

```
output_buffering = On
safe_mode = Off
```